# Override Logger's appender inherited from root in Logback

Tags: logging, logback, slf4j

We know that `logger` inherits the `root`'s configurations in Logback.

For example:

```
<root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

<logger name="com.thinkaurelius.thrift" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.apache.cassandra.transport" level="DEBUG">
   <appender-ref ref="QUERYLOGGER" />
</logger>
```

In this `logback.xml`, we defined a `root` which has two appenders:

1. `FILE` (redirect output to a file)
2. `STDOUT` (terminal printer)

We also add two `loggers` in which we defined some customized logging level and customized appender. For example: all DEBUG log will go to QUERYLOGGER appender  (which is the other file on disk) for `org.apache.cassandra.transport`

**However,  all the debug info of `org.apache.cassandra.transport` also appear in `STDOUT` and `FILE` because it inherits the config from `root`.**

What if I want to disable `STDOUT` and `FILE` appender but keep `QUERYLOGGER` appender for only `org.apache.cassandra.transport` logger?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading the documentation of logback. I myself found the answer towards this specific question:

`<logger>` tag supports an attribute called `additivity` which by defaults is set to `true`. Turn this value to `false` will prevent this logger from inheriting from parents.

For this case:

```
<logger name="org.apache.cassandra.transport" level="DEBUG" additivity='false'>
  <appender-ref ref="QUERYLOGGER" />
</logger>
```

[Logback additivity example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-additivity-example/)

[Logback documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#loggerElement)